# Use Variable in viewDidLoad

Tags: xcode, variables, swift, viewdidload

The Label `etikett1` does output the value of variable `test1` correctly, but the Label `etikett2` is not working. How I can get the value of variable `test2` declared in viewDidLoad?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var etikett1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var etikett2: UILabel!

    @IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
        let test1 = "hello 1"
        etikett1.text = test1  
        etikett2.text = test2       
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let test2 = "hello 2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some more details to your question because it's not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Why don't you just declare test2 in func button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either declare `test2` as an instance variable, alongside your two labels, or assign the `text` property of `etikket2` inside `viewDidLoad`:

**Method 1:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var etikett1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var etikett2: UILabel!
    let test2 = "hello 2"

    @IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
        let test1 = "hello 1"
        etikett1.text = test1  
        etikett2.text = test2       
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let test2 = "hello 2"
    etikett2.text = test2
}
```